# Count number of occurrences in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 2 lists like this:

```
prefix = ['b', 'bo', 'br'] 
word = ['bring', 'boring', 'bold', 'bells']
```

How do I count how many times is each prefixes within the list word?

It should return

```
[4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: What did you try so far? you need nested loops to iterate both list and finding the appearance of items of first list in second list using `in` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using list comprehension, [`str.startswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

```
[sum(w.startswith(p) for w in word) for p in prefix] # [4, 2, 1]
```

Comment: great, thank you! now can you give me that answer with map, reduce or filter function? i'm trying to understand how it works

Comment: @RealQ the equivalent functionality could be achieved using  `map(lambda p: sum(w.startswith(p) for w in word), prefix)`

Comment: @RealQ oh, and `map(sum, ((w.startswith(p) for w in word) for p in prefix))` of course.